# How to implement a Cons list prepend without a useless assignment?

Tags: rust, cons

I am going through [Testcase: linked-list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum/testcase_linked_list.html) in *Rust by Example*. RBE has implemented `prepend` method by passing `self` by value:

```
fn prepend(self, elem: u32) -> List {
    // `Cons` also has type List
    Cons(elem, Box::new(self))
}
```

and calls it as:

```
list = list.prepend(1);
list = list.prepend(2);
list = list.prepend(3);
```

I want to use `&mut self` and not assign `list` over and over, like so:

```
list.prepend("asd");
list.prepend("def");
list.prepend("jkl");
```

I tried:

```
enum LinkedList<T> {
    Cons(T, Box<LinkedList<T>>),
    Nil
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T> where T: Copy {
    fn prepend(&mut self, value: T) {
        let tail = mem::replace(self, Nil);
        *self = Cons(value, Box::new(tail));
    }
}
```

This works, but I am doing a useless assignment of `Nil` to `self`. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps using `mem::replace` or something else?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the "useless" operation in safe code. You need _something_ to pass to `Box::new()`, and the tail can't be moved out of the borrowed context. That said, I don't think that operation has any measurable performance impact, since the runtime of `prepend()` is dominated by the memory allocation. The compiler may even be able to optiimise the redundant step away.

Comment: From the linked duplicate: *simultaneously replace it with `Nil`, so that the `self` reference is never invalid*. This is why it's needed in safe Rust.